# Binomial distribution conditional probability

Tags: binomial-distribution, conditional-probability, negative-binomial-distribution

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the probability of tossing k heads in n trials of a fair coin?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/45660/what-is-the-probability-of-tossing-k-heads-in-n-trials-of-a-fair-coin)

What is the probability of tossing $k$ heads in $n$ trials conditional that in first $t$ attempts there was one head? And the coin is fair.

Is it $p(k - 1, n - t)$?