# What is the probability of tossing k heads in n trials of a fair coin?

Tags: binomial-distribution, conditional-probability

Conditional on the fact that during the first t trials coin landed once on heads.

Comment: Welcome to the site.  If this is homework it should have the homework tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have answered your own question. Since the first $t$ trials are known the probability of obtaining $k-1$ heads in the remaining trails is binomial and hence the probability for $k-1$ successes is given by

$p(k-1) = \binom{n-t}{k-1} p^{k-1}(1-p)^{n-t-k+1}$

Answer (score 1):

yes it is p(k-1,n-t) :) there are n-t trials remaining and probability of getting k-1 more heads will be p(k-1,n-t)